# Convert string to an integer

Tags: string, vb.net, integer, converters

I'm having trouble converting a String to Integer in VB.net

I tried the following, but it wont quite work:

Code:

1:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    My.Settings.ydelay = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text)
End Sub
```

2:

```
My.Settings.ydelay = Textbox3.Text
My.Settings.ydelay = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox3.Text)
```

3:

```
My.Settings.ydelay = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox.3Text)
My.Settings.ydelay = Textbox3.Text
```

4:

```
My.Settings.ydelay = Textbox3.Text
Convert.ToInt32(Textbox3.Text, My.Settings.ydelay)
```

I am pretty much going crazy over this maybe im just missing a little detail but I cant figure it out. Help would really be appreciated if you need more details let me know.

Comment: Why do you have two lines of code in each case?  You are performing one conversion so you only need one line of code. `Convert.ToInt32` will work perfectly well as long as the `String` you pass actually does represent an integer.. It should be obvious that you can convert "Hello World" or an empty `String` to a number. You should be validating before converting, or you could do both in one go with `Integer.TryParse`.

Comment: @Rango No they are just containing integer numbers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Those were just variations that I tried. Could you show me an example of the right  way to do it?

Comment: Firstly, if you want examples then you need to search the web for them. You don't need me to post yet another example of something that is already out there in many places. Secondly, how about you tell us EXACTLY what actually happens when you use the code you already have because some of them would work if what you were telling us was true, so what you're telling us is not true.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your ydelay setting in project properties is set to Scope User because Application scope is Read Only. Then double check the datatype is Integer.

You will not see the changes in Project Properties. They are stored in User.config. Location: C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Local\TestCode2\TestCode2.exe_Url_aq2yohztn2r23tmvf0pbczm25mx0yx11\1.0.0.0  for my project which is named TestCode2.

Lo and behold...

```
        <setting name="ydelay" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1</value>
        </setting>
```

If you were to go to another computer the setting for ydelay would be the initial value as shown in the Project Properties. This makes sense because it is a "User" setting and each user will have there own setting.

As to the code. I don't like the TextChanged event. It fires every time a key is pressed; that includes backspace. Maybe Leave will work for you.

.TryParse is a good way to check input. It does double duty by setting a variable and returning a boolean so it fits right into an If statement.

```
Private Sub TextBox16_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox16.Leave
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox16.Text, i) Then
        My.Settings.ydelay = i
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in TextBox 16")
        TextBox16.Select() 'If you want to insist
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert string to integer. Check if you input is just a number.

is use this code on textbox keypress

```
  If (e.KeyChar <= ChrW(47)) Or (e.KeyChar >= ChrW(58)) Then
            If e.KeyChar = vbBack Then
            Else
                e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            End If
        Else
        End If
        If sender.text = "" Then
            sender.text = 0
        End If
```

after that i just use `Cint(textboxt.text)`